# Align two tables vertically across one page in appendix

Tags: tables, align, margins

I want to align two tables respectively on one page having the same space to the top and bottom margin. Here is a small MWE of my tables (that are much larger)

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt!] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{a} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}lcccccc} 
\toprule
 a & b  & c & d  \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
a & 14.40 $\%$ & 60.99 $\%$ & Yes  \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Table2
\begin{table}[hbt!] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{b} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}ccccccc} 
\toprule
  & a & b & c & 
  d & e \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & 0.3 & 16.98 $\%$ & 13.31 $\%$    & 17.86 $\%$    & 2.98 $\%$
 \\ 
 & 0.5 & 14.38 $\%$& 10.17 $\%$ & 18.18 $\%$    &   2.98 $\%$ \\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[h] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{c} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}clcccccc} 
\toprule
  & a & b & d & d &e & f & g \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & 0.3 & 16.64 $\%$ & 15.32 $\%$ & 16.77 $\%$ & 11.87 $\%$  & 15.65 $\%$ & 12.94 $\%$ \\ 
 & 0.5 & 15.59 $\%$ & 11.25 $\%$ & 14.72 $\%$ & 7.95 $\%$  \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{d} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}clcccccc} 
\toprule
  & a & b & c & d & e & f & g  \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & 0.3 & 24.72 $\%$ & 20.96 $\%$ & 48.54 $\%$   & 86.44 $\%$ & 80.20 $\%$ & 63.64 $\%$ 
 \\ 
 & 0.5 & 11.60 $\%$& 7.94 $\%$  &   40.98 $\%$  &   74.70 $\%$  &   75.96 $\%$ &    42.22 $\%$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In particular, I want that Table 1 and 2 are on one page "equally distributed" and the same for Table 3 and 4 on a new page.

Comment: I dit it with "\hfill\mbox{}\vfill" before and after each table, not the most elegant way but it works

Comment: I wonder why you like to have this small tables, which together occupay only about 2/3 of page on two pages? To achieve what you like, set all table placement to `[p]` and `\newpage` repalce with `\clearpage`.

Comment: Just ou of idle curiosity: Why do you write `\hline \\[-1.8ex]` when you could be writing `\midrule`?

Comment: @Zarko my real tables are not that small, it was just to provide an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See, if the following is what you lookinng for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            threeparttable}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}  %

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=2.2{\,\%}}
  \caption{d}
\begin{tabular}{c*{2}{S<{\,\%}} c }
    \toprule
a   & \mcc{b}   & \mcc{c}   & d     \\
    \midrule
a   & 14.40     & 60.99     & Yes  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%Table2
\begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=2.2{\,\%}}
  \caption{d}
\begin{tabular}{c*{5}{S<{\,\%}}}
    \toprule
a   & \mcc{b}   & \mcc{c}   & \mcc{d}   & \mcc{e}       \\
    \midrule
0.3 & 16.98     & 13.31     & 17.86     & 2.98          \\
0.5 & 14.38     & 10.17     & 18.18     & 2.98          \\
    \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=2.2{\,\%}}
  \caption{d}
\begin{tabular}{c*{7}{S<{\,\%}}}
    \toprule
a   & \mcc{b}   & \mcc{c}   & \mcc{d}   & \mcc{e}   & \mcc{f}   & \mcc{g}   \\
    \midrule
0.3 & 16.64     & 15.32     & 16.77     & 11.87     & 15.65     & 12.94     \\
0.5 & 15.59     & 11.25     & 14.72     &  7.95     & \mcc{}    & \mcc{}    \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=2.2{\,\%}}
  \caption{d}
\begin{tabular}{c*{7}{S<{\%}}}
    \toprule
a   & \mcc{b}   & \mcc{c}   & \mcc{d}   & \mcc{e}   & \mcc{f}   & \mcc{g}   \\
    \midrule
0.3 & 24.72     & 20.96     & 48.54     & 86.44     & 80.20     & 63.64     \\
0.5 & 11.60     & 7.94      & 40.98     & 74.70     & 75.96     & 42.22     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

- From your MWE I remove all `threeparttable` since I didn't see what you need it (you have not `tablenotes`, however it is not to difficult to return them back).
- For column with numbers I use `S` column type that they are aligned at decimal points
- As I already mentioned in my comment, for placement options I use `[p]` and `\clearpage` instead `\newpage`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that uses one `table[p]` environment per page, with two `tabular` environments per `table`.

I would also recommend replacing all instances of `\hline \\[-1.8ex]` with `\midrule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] 
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
 \caption{a} 
\begin{tabular}{lccc} 
\toprule
 a & b & c & d \\ 
\midrule 
 a & 14.40 $\%$ & 60.99 $\%$ & Yes \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{b} 
\begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
\toprule
 a & b & c & d & e \\ 
\midrule 
 0.3 & 16.98 $\%$ & 13.31 $\%$ & 17.86 $\%$ & 2.98 $\%$ \\ 
 0.5 & 14.38 $\%$ & 10.17 $\%$ & 18.18 $\%$ & 2.98 $\%$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{c} 
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} 
\toprule
 a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ 
\midrule 
 0.3 & 16.64 $\%$ & 15.32 $\%$ & 16.77 $\%$ & 11.87 $\%$  & 15.65 $\%$ & 12.94 $\%$ \\ 
 0.5 & 15.59 $\%$ & 11.25 $\%$ & 14.72 $\%$ & 7.95 $\%$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{d} 
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} 
\toprule
 a & b & c & d & e & f & g  \\ 
\midrule 
 0.3 & 24.72 $\%$ & 20.96 $\%$ & 48.54 $\%$ & 86.44 $\%$ & 80.20 $\%$ & 63.64 $\%$ \\ 
 0.5 & 11.60 $\%$ &  7.94 $\%$ & 40.98 $\%$ & 74.70 $\%$ & 75.96 $\%$ & 42.22 $\%$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```